Looking for confirmation of quaternion form for rotation Matrix
Looking for confirmation of understanding is correct.
Section 1
Given a point vector
P = ( p1, p2, p3)
converted to quaternion as
p = [ 0, p1, p2, p3 ]
axis of rotation A defined as the unit vector
A = [ a1i, a2j, a3k ]
and the quaternion for rotation of angle  around axis A defined as
q = [ cos(/2), sin(/2)A ]
and its inverted quaternion as
q' = [ cos(/2), -sin(/2)A ]
The active rotation (rotation of the object in space, not rotation of space around the object) is defined as
p' = q' p q


Section 2
(note: this section was identified as incorrect in Tim Wescott's response.)
I can't recall where, but I believe that I saw somewhere that the Rotation Matrix R is defined as
R = q' q
such that
p' = R p
provides the simplified form expressed with the Rotation Matrix.


Question 1:  Does all from Section 1 and Section 2 present a correct summary ?


Section 3
Question 2:  Do I have to apply a translation T to all points such that the center of rotation is coincident with origin of the 3D space coordinate system before performing rotations every time, followed by the reverse translation -T for correct final placement of all where it should be?

$q'q$ does not give you a rotation matrix, nor even a matrix.

Thank you, Nicholas.


Question 1:  Is the above a correct summary ?

No.  For any quaternion $q$, where $q'$ is the conjugation operator, $q q' = q' q = \| q \|^2$, i.e. a real number equal to the square of the quaternion's length.  It's the exact equivalent for any complex number $c$ multiplied by its complex conjugate.
In the case of a rotation quaternion, $q q' = 1$.  You can work this out with pencil and paper -- it'll be good for your soul.
Everything leading up to that false identity is correct, however.

Question 2:  Do I have to apply a translation T to all points such that the center of rotation is coincident with origin of the 3D space coordinate system before performing rotations every time, followed by the reverse translation -T for correct final placement of all where it should be?

Once you arrive at a rotation matrix that actually works, if you want to rotate a collection of points about some center point, using a quaternion (or a rotation matrix), then yes -- you need to translate your center point to zero, do the rotation, then translate everything back.

Thank you, Tim.  Much appreciated!

Tim, just to clarify, the identify that you are referring to is that of R = q' q .  Correct?

If your $\mathbf R$ is the rotation matrix, then no.  The product of a quaternion with its conjugate is the square of its magnitude.  That is a real, non-negative number -- not a matrix.

What I meant to say is that the expression was incorrect.  Correct?

If $\mathbf R$ is expected to be a rotation matrix, then $\mathbf R = q q'$ is incorrect.  You can calculate a rotation matrix from the elements of a quaternion, but it's not a direct arithmetic operation.
